# Picture and text on same row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use codepen to put an image on the right side of the screen with some text on the left side at the same height.  I originally used a boostrap container to place them in slots, but I was told that's what caused my codepen to be jumbled when I linked it to the freecodecamp help.  I also tried floating the image, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

This is my html:

```
<div style="background-color:#999; overflow:hidden;" class="well">
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1 class=" text-align-vertically text-center white-text"> <br> <br> <br> Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer, with practical experience in project management, branding strategy, and creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture. <br> <br> <br> <br> </h1> 
<h1 class="text-center white-text"> Web Developer -       User Experience Designer - Graphic Artist <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> </h1>

<img class="smaller-image1 image-margins circular-image resize-image" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-b5YzMfLsjTY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADw/QrZ6m4H7wkA/photo.jpg" alt="my photo">
    </div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
smaller-image1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-margins {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

 .circular-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.resize-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: You can use flex https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 0):

you need to get rid of

```
.resize-image {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

because it makes the image take all the available area and leave no room for the text in the same line.
you also need to put the image before the text in your html file.

[live example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNYorE)

Comment: Thank you!  For some reason now it has my text not adding page breaks between them like it should.

Comment: Could you upload the code causing you problem, so we can help ??